# Changing LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME for LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT

Tags: c++, winapi, locale

Is there a way to change "LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME" on runtime? 
I would like to set another language for "LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME" on runtime and when queried by "GetLocaleInfo", it should be new language instead of system default.
By the way, it seems, you can't set "LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME" by using "SetLocaleInfo".
Thank you in advance for your kind concern.

Comment: Do you want to change just `LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME`, or do you want to change the actual language (with all its parameters, not just `LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME`)?

Comment: @Raymond Chen:For my case, it is enough to change just LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, however it wouldn't be a problem to change actual language.

Comment: Should this be system-wide or just for your own process?

Comment: @MSalters: Just for my process.

Comment: What parameters are being passed to GetLocaleInfo? Specifically, what lcid are you requesting? (And why don't you just fix the code that calls GetLocaleInfo?)

Comment: @Raymond Chen: GetLocaleInfo call is made by an external component therefore code fix is out of option. I hooked the GetLocaleInfo info and the parameters are LCID: LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT and LCTYPE: LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME.

Comment: In which case you can try using `SetThreadLocale` to change the locale for the current thread.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME` is a constant (C++ #define) so you cannot really change it on runtime. If I understand you correctly, you want to replace GetLocaleInfo calls with this value as a first argument so that effectively another argument is passed to the API.

It would not be a big deal if it was all in your code (code edit and binary rebuild could really do the job), and I can assume that you want this rather to have effect for something you only have in binary.

Provided that the guesswork above is correct, and especially you want it just for your process, you could perhaps hook GetLocaleInfo entry point and patch it in order to intercept the call and update arguments. It is not something easy or safe to use though, you will have to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you, however I have already hooked and it is working but I am looking for a more safe and clean solution, if possible.

Comment: I think, there is on way without hooking. I will accept this, thank you.